# Creating a command to clear clipboard in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, copy-paste, clipboard

I would like to make a command that will clear (reset) Clipboard while I am using Excel 2010.

I would prefer this as a button in Excel, but it can be a shortcut on the desktop as well.

Is there any way to make something like this in Windows 7(32-bit).

I am making this because as I copy data from one excel file to another, I run out of free RAM memory and at that point my computer crashes.

Comment: You could easily write a script in AutoIt or autohotkey to clear the clipboard contents. In AutoIt, ClipPut() passing an empty string will clear the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done within the excel in two steps.

Fist step

[image: Step One]

Second step

[image: Step Two]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [AutoIt (full installation)](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)
2. Open `SciTE Script Editor`
3. Write `ClipPut("")` and save the file.
4. Open `Compile Script to .exe (x86)`, browse to you script file you have created earlier and choose a destination (exe) file and click `Convert`

Now whenever you run it it will clear the clipboard (you also can uninstall autoit now, because the exe file is standalone).